# Show/Hide an additional checkout field when ticking a checkbox in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

My WooCommerce store has 2 different products.

In check out page, if customer buy a normal product, he only fill normal billing fields.

But if this customer buy a second product, the customer must be tick a checkbox that will make appear an additional field.

Anyone could help me solve this problem?

Comment: You don't need a checkbox at all, just show the additional field if the corresponding product is added to the cart.  Hide it when the other product is added.

Comment: My mean is I use wordpress and intergrate woocommerce for manager products and payment. I want to show additional field when user tick check box at CHECK OUT page, and hide if user doesn't tick.

Comment: Try and write the code yourself then I will help you out with it but at least have an attempt.

Comment: Thanks very much! I had try to add your code to my functions.php but when I update, it's appear error can loading page. Could You please tell me where I put your code ? Thanks again!

Comment: This is my code in functions.php: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aae804a4f74e82bd9afee189c5752ccdc9fc273b

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set in the function your 2 product IDS and to put the correct texts for your custom checkout fields. The code below will conditionally display a checkbox when both products are in cart. When customer will tick the checkbox an additional text field will appear:

```
// Add  fields to the checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_fields' );
function custom_checkout_fields( $checkout ) {

    // Set HERE below your different product IDs
    $product_1_id = 37; // Normal product
    $product_2_id = 67; // Specific product (second product)
    $has_id_1 = $has_id_2 = false;
    
    // Check if products are in cart
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( $cart_item['product_id'] == $product_1_id ) $has_id_1 = true;
        if( $cart_item['product_id'] == $product_2_id ) $has_id_2 = true;
    }
    
    // Display conditionally Custom checkout Fields (when both products are in cart)
    if( $has_id_1 && $has_id_2 ){

        echo '<div id="custom_checkout_fields">';

        // The Check box
        woocommerce_form_field( 'my_checkbox', array(
            'type'          => 'checkbox',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Fill in this field'),
            'placeholder'   => __('Enter something'),
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_checkbox' ));

        // The hidden field
        woocommerce_form_field( 'my_text_field', array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Fill in this field'),
            'placeholder'   => __('Enter something'),
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_text_field' ));

        echo '</div>';

        $required = esc_attr__( 'required', 'woocommerce' );
        
        // The jQuery Script
        ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($){
                // Initialising variables
                var textField = 'p#my_text_field_field',
                    checkboxField = 'input[name^="my_checkbox"]',
                    required = '<abbr class="required" title="<?php echo $required; ?>">*</abbr>'; // Required html

                // Initialising at start (Hidding the text field)
                $(textField).hide(function(){
                    $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                    $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                    $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field");
                    if( $(textField+' > label > abbr').html() != undefined )
                        $(textField+' label > .required').remove();
                });

                // When Checkbox is checked / unchecked (Live event)
                $( checkboxField ).click( function() {
                    if( $(this).prop('checked') == true )
                        $(textField).show(function(){
                            $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                            $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                            $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field");
                            if( $(textField+' > label > abbr').html() == undefined )
                                $(textField+' label').append(required);
                        });
                    else
                        $(textField).hide(function(){
                            $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                            $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                            $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field");
                            if( $(textField+' > label > abbr').html() != undefined )
                                $(textField+' label > .required').remove();
                        });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php

    }
}

// Update the order meta with field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['my_text_field'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, __('My Field'), sanitize_text_field( $_POST['my_text_field'] ) );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme or in any plugin file).*

Tested and Works in WooCommerce 3+

---

Related official developer documentation: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)